# BIND9 with ISC-DHCP-SERVER: Unable to add forward map from ... REFUSED for one machine

Tags: dns, bind, dhcp

I have BIND9 and ISC-DHCP running for a few years w/o and config changes.

New machines get an IP allocated and a forward map added to DNS.

However, one machine is getting this error.

`Unable to add forward map from Tesla_Model_3.argylecourt.lan to 192.168.1.69: REFUSED`

The log for a few machines looks like this (the second last block has the REFUSED error):

```
Nov 29 07:21:34 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.66 to e4:5e:37:a1:02:57 (A2801191251) via eth0
Nov 29 07:21:34 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.66 (192.168.1.8) from e4:5e:37:a1:02:57 (A2801191251) via eth0
Nov 29 07:21:34 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.66 to e4:5e:37:a1:02:57 (A2801191251) via eth0
Nov 29 07:21:34 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: Added reverse map from 66.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa to A2801191251.int.abc.net.au
Nov 29 07:21:38 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: reuse_lease: lease age 4 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 192.168.1.66
Nov 29 07:21:38 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.66 from e4:5e:37:a1:02:57 (A2801191251) via eth0
Nov 29 07:21:38 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.66 to e4:5e:37:a1:02:57 (A2801191251) via eth0

Nov 29 07:28:19 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.94 (192.168.1.8) from 5f:a9:50:16:04:75 (WIZnet160475) via eth0
Nov 29 07:28:19 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: Wrote 0 deleted host decls to leases file.
Nov 29 07:28:19 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: Wrote 0 new dynamic host decls to leases file.
Nov 29 07:28:19 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: Wrote 50 leases to leases file.
Nov 29 07:28:19 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.94 to 5f:a9:50:16:04:75 (WIZnet160475) via eth0

Nov 29 07:58:09 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.56 (192.168.1.8) from 4d:61:78:47:39:38 (WIZnet473938) via eth0
Nov 29 07:58:09 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.56 to 4d:61:78:47:39:38 (WIZnet473938) via eth0

Nov 29 08:21:17 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.61 (192.168.1.8) from 4d:61:78:47:39:37 (WIZnet473937) via eth0
Nov 29 08:21:17 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.61 to 4d:61:78:47:39:37 (WIZnet473937) via eth0
Nov 29 08:28:49 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPDISCOVER from 68:d7:9a:02:9e:ae (UAP-AC-Mesh1) via eth0
Nov 29 08:28:50 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.79 to 68:d7:9a:02:9e:ae (UAP-AC-Mesh1) via eth0

Nov 29 08:28:50 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.79 (192.168.1.8) from 68:d7:9a:02:9e:ae (UAP-AC-Mesh1) via eth0
Nov 29 08:28:50 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.79 to 68:d7:9a:02:9e:ae (UAP-AC-Mesh1) via eth0

Nov 29 09:16:28 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.69 from 4c:fc:aa:1f:9d:13 via eth0
Nov 29 09:16:28 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.69 to 4c:fc:aa:1f:9d:13 (Tesla_Model_3) via eth0
Nov 29 09:16:28 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: Unable to add forward map from Tesla_Model_3.argylecourt.lan to 192.168.1.69: REFUSED

Nov 29 09:40:24 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.59 (192.168.1.8) from 5f:34:33:33:54:58 (WIZnet335458) via eth0
Nov 29 09:40:24 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.59 to 5f:34:33:33:54:58 (WIZnet335458) via eth0
```

I have no idea how to solve this. I did read a few posts, but these  pointed to resolv.conf, and DNS config files, which I felt do no not apply.

Why only this machine? And not any others?

I am happy to provide any config that aids solving this though.

The machine running BIND/DHCP:

```
   Static hostname: rpi32
  Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
            Kernel: Linux 4.14.34-v7+
      Architecture: arm

● bind9.service - BIND Domain Name Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bind9.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-06-12 16:18:11 AEST; 5 months 17 days ago
     Docs: man:named(8)
 Main PID: 10866 (named)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bind9.service
           └─10866 /usr/sbin/named -4 -u bind

Nov 29 07:21:34 rpi32 named[10866]: zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: sending notifies (serial 2019080932)
Nov 29 09:16:28 rpi32 named[10866]: client @0x712325b8 127.0.0.1#48853/key dhcp_updater: signer "dhcp_updater" approved
Nov 29 09:16:28 rpi32 named[10866]: zone argylecourt.lan/IN: Tesla_Model_3.argylecourt.lan/A: bad owner name (check-names)
Nov 29 10:47:54 rpi32 named[10866]: client @0x7016cba8 127.0.0.1#43559/key dhcp_updater: updating zone 'argylecourt.lan/IN': update unsuccessful: lantronix.argylecourt.lan: 'name n$
Nov 29 10:47:54 rpi32 named[10866]: client @0x70002020 127.0.0.1#54555/key dhcp_updater: signer "dhcp_updater" approved
Nov 29 10:47:54 rpi32 named[10866]: client @0x70002020 127.0.0.1#54555/key dhcp_updater: updating zone 'argylecourt.lan/IN': deleting rrset at 'lantronix.argylecourt.lan' A
Nov 29 10:47:54 rpi32 named[10866]: client @0x70002020 127.0.0.1#54555/key dhcp_updater: updating zone 'argylecourt.lan/IN': adding an RR at 'lantronix.argylecourt.lan' A 192.168.1$
Nov 29 10:47:54 rpi32 named[10866]: client @0x701f0ff0 127.0.0.1#45643/key dhcp_updater: signer "dhcp_updater" approved
Nov 29 10:47:54 rpi32 named[10866]: client @0x701f0ff0 127.0.0.1#45643/key dhcp_updater: updating zone '1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN': deleting rrset at '11.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa' PTR
Nov 29 10:47:54 rpi32 named[10866]: client @0x701f0ff0 127.0.0.1#45643/key dhcp_updater: updating zone '1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN': adding an RR at '11.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa' PTR $


● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-07-03 20:59:59 AEST; 4 months 26 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
   CGroup: /system.slice/isc-dhcp-server.service
           └─27581 /usr/sbin/dhcpd -4 -q -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf eth0

Nov 29 09:16:28 rpi32 dhcpd[27581]: Unable to add forward map from Tesla_Model_3.argylecourt.lan
```

[edit1] I updated the BIND status messages... and saw this **(bad owner name (check-names)**):

```
Nov 29 09:16:28 rpi32 named[10866]: zone argylecourt.lan/IN: Tesla_Model_3.argylecourt.lan/A: bad owner name (check-names)
```

Looking into this now.... but it seems underscores are not allowed in A records.

Answer (score 0):

Further research revealed: Underscore characters are not permitted in domain names in accordance with RFC 1035, which only allows letters, digits and hyphens in non_TXT records.

Comment: That is a little more complicated than that. In DNS lingo, There are domain names (basically any name with any characters) and then hostnames that are a subset also called LDH. Some records use hostnames (`A`,`AAAA`,`NS`, `MX` exchange, etc.) some use domain names (`TXT`,`CNAME`, etc.). `named-checkzone` is a good tool to verify the syntax of the content of your zonefile.

Comment: In this case the name could not be written; it is not in the zone file; which at configuration was used to check syntax.

Comment: You can put the name in a fake zonefile and run `named-checkzone` on it. You would then see basically the same error message as the one you reported in your logfile.